# Sum up the fields in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

In below linq statement i need to sum totalhours,directhours & Indirect Hours by grouping by Name

this could be a noob question since i am new to Linq.

```
var Empl = from Evw in EViews.AsEnumerable()
            where Evw.Field<string>("Type") == "Egh" &&
                  Evw.Field<string>("Org") == orgname
                  select new
                  {
                    RowLabel = (string)Evw["Name"],
                    TotalHours = (decimal)Evw["TotalHours"],
                    DirectHours = (decimal)Evw["DirectHours"],
                    IndirectHours = (decimal)Evw["IndirectHours"],
                   };
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Something like `var res = Empl.GroupBy(x=>x.RowLabel).Select(g=>new{RowLabel=g.Key, SumTotalHours = g.Sum(x=>x.TotalHours ) });`

Answer (score 0):

Please check tihs [Article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

You can get group value this LINQ

```
 var Empl = from Evw in EViews.AsEnumerable()
                where Evw.Field<string>("Type") == "Egh" &&
                      Evw.Field<string>("Org") == orgname
                      group Evw by Evw.Name into g
                      select new
                      {
                        RowLabel = g.Key,
                        TotalHours = g.Sum(x=>x.TotalHours)
                       };
```